# detect audio in html xcode

Tags: xcode, audio, uiwebview, detect

I have a QR code reader in X Code, and when it detects a web page it should open a web view.
It works like a charm, though it can't detect an audio file.
I have a link, which loads an audio in a browser, and in my app redirects to an error.
This is the [url](http://net.lib.byu.edu/~mjw243/01_Track_1.html).

In a browser the `.html` become mp3 and the audio is playing automatically.

How can I detect whether it is an audio or a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you can do is hit the URL and look at the `Content-Type` header returned.

You can use a `HEAD` request where supported, and fall back to `GET` if needed, and simply disconnect once you have the appropriate headers.

Comment: @IOSDEV, A `HEAD` request is for headers only.  There would be no content to display.